# Bootstrap Progress Bar Start Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, progress-bar

I am using a bootstrap progress bar which looks really nice.  I've read up on some of the documentation as seen here https://github.com/minddust/bootstrap-progressbar.

I was wondering if there was a simple way to change the start value (so not 0), like my app does every time. I really need to dive into javascript and jquery but I haven't gotten there yet.

So I work with the simple:

```
          <div class="progress progress-striped active">
            <div class="progress-bar six-sec-ease-in-out" role="progressbar"  aria-valuetransitiongoal="33"></div>
          </div>
```

is my control from the view, and the actual JS comes from here

```
      $(window).ready(function(e){
              $.each($('div.progress-bar'),function(){
                $(this).css('width', $(this).attr('aria-valuetransitiongoal')+'%');
              });
```

The goal is to use this as a progress bar, where-in I could add start values at each of the 3pages. Page one 0 (which is default so this wouldn't need to change) with the aria-valuetransitiongoal of 33.  Page two start at 33% with the aria valuetransitiongoal of 66% etc.  As of now, I set the goal to the right value, but each page load restarts the value to 0.

Update: Is local storage the best way...?

Comment: You can store the progress value in localstorage and then retrieve the value whenever you need to and then update the localstorage with the updated progress value.

Comment: Would you mind providing some code? Not sure about "local storage."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the width of the "progress-bar".

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar six-sec-ease-in-out" role="progressbar" style="width:33%"></div>
</div>
```

You can also set the width dynamically via function call or variable (returning "value%" e.g. 20%).

style="width:' + variable/functionCall + '"